# Ranking of which more replied my doubts

Tags: support

I believe that is not so relevant this question, because it is a mere curiosity.
So I have several questions asked on this forum that were answered by several colleagues. It is possible to create a table that shows the ranking of which more replied my doubts?

Comment: Sure, you can query the data here http://data.stackexchange.com using SQL